# How to configure mailgun add-on on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, mailgun

I hope to send mails from heroku domain `<appname>@herokuapp.com`.

First, I installed mailgun add-on on heroku and tried sending mails, but it shows

```
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.')
```

However, I create domain in mailgun page
`<appname>@herokuapp.com`
It needs to verify domain.

Should I use which one as domain?
And how can I configure them well?
Many thanks.

`heroku config:edit`
shows

```
MAILGUN_API_KEY=3fe2*****ae1a
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox*****d5cb.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_KEY=3fe2****ae1a
MAILGUN_PUBLIC_KEY=pubkey-b******a
MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN='postmaster@sandbox*******.mailgun.org'
MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD=b018******7840
MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT=587
MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER=smtp.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_VALIDATIONS_PUBLIC_KEY='[200]'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first test you should follow Mailgun response as seen above:

Configure valid recipient(s) email address(es) in Mailgun.